# Swift 1.2 Concatenate String

Tags: swift

I'm getting errors when concatenating string:

```
let likeKey = "like-" + foodPhotoObjects[indexPath.row].objectId
```

Error

```
binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'String?!'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have an implicitly-wrapped optional of an optional string, something like this:

```
struct Thing {
    let objectId: String?!
}

let foodPhotoObjects: [Thing] = [Thing(objectId: "2")]
```

With any doubly-wrapped optional, to get to the object inside you’d need to unwrap it twice:

```
// first unwrap the String?! into a String?
if let outer = foodPhotoObjects[0].objectId,
// then unwrap that String? into a String
       inner = outer {

    //  inner is now a String
    println("like-\(inner)")

}
```

The key here is even though the outer optional is implicit (i.e. `!` rather than `?`), you can still unwrap implicit optionals using `if let`, so the implicitness is irrelevant when doing this.

An alternative way of handling this kind of thing, rather than if-let, is to use `map`:

```
let concatedString = foodPhotoObjects[indexPath.row].objectId.map { 
    "like-" + $0 
} ?? ""
```

`map` on an optional means: if the optional contains a value, change the value using this function and return that as an optional, otherwise return `nil`.  So, unwrap the `String?` and prepend “like” to it.

`??` on an optional means: if the preceding value is `nil`, replace it with the default on the right-hand side (the empty string), otherwise unwrap it and return that (i.e. the value we just mapped).

Now for the tricky part: because the value we’re calling `map` on is an implicit optional, it will be implicitly unwrapped – that is, the `map` is being called on the inner `String?` rather than on the `String?!`.  This is unlike the case with `if let` where that was run on the implicit optional first, then the inner optional.

As with all implicit optionals, there’s a risk that they might actually be `nil` in which case your code would blow up, like so:

```
let explode = Thing(objectId: nil)
// the next line will generate fatal error: unexpectedly
// found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
explode.objectId.map { "like-" + $0 }
```

If this is a concern, you could guard against it with some optional chaining:

```
// note, ? after objectId
let concatedString = foodPhotoObjects[indexPath.row].objectId?.map {
    "like-" + $0
} ?? ""
```

This snippet could win a prize for most optional-handling techniques crammed into a single statement… but it should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Swift does not do implicit conversion, even if both are of same type and  one of them is of optional type.

Try this.

```
var concatedString = ""
if let foodphoto = foodPhotoObjects[indexPath.row].objectId as? String {
  concatedString = "like-" + foodphoto

}
```

Comment: is this a new rule with 1.2?

Comment: You could also write that as `let concatedString = foodPhotoObjects[indexPath.row].objectId.map { "like-" + $0 } ?? ""`

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity this comment worked for me while the answer did not. but i'm not sure i understand what's happening

Comment: OK I’ll turn it into an answer and try explaining a bit more.  What’s the type of `foodPhotoObjects` if you option-click it?

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity wow thanks for the detailed answer. `foodPhotoObjects` is type `[AnyObject]`